# Jquery changes elements when wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Jquery to get a response from a server and replace a specific element with the one in the Response using the following code:

```
//msg is the returned message from the response
//$row is the element being replaced
var $newRow = $(msg).find('#'+$row.attr('id'));
$row.replaceWith($newRow);
```

now there is a select box in msg with the following html code(outer element included):

```
<div class="grid-cell-value">
    <input type="number" data-field="quantity" value="60.7" disabled />
    <select data-field="monetary_unit" value="12" disabled />
        <option value="12" selected="selected">EURO</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but when I wrap `msg` in Jquery this is what happens to the select Element.(note the `option` element is outside the `select` element.

```
<div class="grid-cell-value">
    <input type="number" data-field="quantity" value="60.7" disabled="">
    <select data-field="monetary_unit" value="12" disabled="">
    </select>
    <option value="12" selected="selected">EURO</option>
</div>
```

---

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select tag is self-closed, pay attention to the /> at the end:

```
<select data-field="monetary_unit" value="12" disabled/> <== here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you loook at your first snippet, you see, that the "select" element looks like this:

```
<select data-field="monetary_unit" value="12" disabled/>
```

Notice the "/" at the end?
The HTML you get from your server is not formated correctly and your SELECT element is treated like a void element. A void element is an element, that doesn't have a close tag, like`<br/>` for example.